# I have some problems with sqoop, when I import mysql data

Tags: mysql, hive, sqoop

I import mysql data with sqoop:

```
sqoop-import-all-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://ip/'database'--username "username" --password **** --hive-import --hive-database 'database '--create-hive-table --as-parquetfile
```

It shows:

```
Hive import and create hive table is not compatible with importing into ParquetFile format.
```

Anybody can help me? thanks

Comment: Does it work for single table?

Comment: Which version of sqoop are you using? I think that  the option "--as-parquetfile" was added in Sqoop 1.4.6 (CDH 5.5).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by removing the --as-parquetfile?